# In freeswitch is there any possibility to reload xml using script

Tags: javascript, python, lua, freeswitch

After adding a user,
how can I reload the `Dial-plan XML` dynamical using script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the EventSocket or simply a shell script calling fscli -x "reloadxml"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I had the need to do this with Python so I thought I would share. Thanks to DanB for the good answer.

Python 3.5:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('fs_cli -x "reloadxml"', shell=True)
```